# Show its type of a variable in Emacs

Tags: variables, types, emacs

I'd like to know whether Emacs has a functionality like Visual Studio's that shows the type of a variable in a C/C++ program.

Could you also let me know if this requires certain packages or tricks.

Comment: Are you asking about letting you know this for some code you are editing? If so, what language?

Comment: Good question: my answer may be completely irrelevant :-)

Comment: @NickD - Yes, I fear so. The question should be deleted as unclear, unless OP clarifies soon. Otherwise, it invites more answers, which might be all over the map.

Answer (score 3):

For C/C++, you can see variable type info by enabling the builtin `semantic-mode` in your C/C++ hooks.  Ensure that `semantic-default-submodes` contains `global-semantic-idle-summary-mode` which is the submode responsible for displaying the type info in the echo area.

You could probably find alternatives using external packages like `irony`.